# Positive definite when multiplying by two matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, positive-definite, positive-semidefinite

I have a square $n \times n$ matrix $\mathbf{X}$ and a non-square $n \times m$ matrix $\mathbf{A}$. The product $\mathbf{M} = \mathbf{A}^T \mathbf{X} \mathbf{A}$ gives a $m \times m$ matrix. If I know that $\mathbf{X}$ is positive definite (or positive-semi definite), is there any way to know $\mathbf{M}$ is positive definite (or positive-semi definite).

If it is not possible, is there any constraints we can make on $\mathbf{A}$ (or maybe $\mathbf{X}$) to have this property? Any pointers will be helpful. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the question! The property explains why a positive-definite correlation matrix implies a positive-definite covariance matrix. The covariance matrix equals the correlation matrix pre- and post-multiplied by the diagonal matrix of standard deviations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since $\mathbf{X}$ is positive-definite, $y^T \mathbf{X} y > 0$ for all $y\in\mathbb{R}^n, y\neq 0$. So for every $x \in \mathbb{R}^m$, we have
$$
 x^T (\mathbf{A}^T \mathbf{X} \mathbf{A})x = (\mathbf{A}x)^T \mathbf{X} (\mathbf{A}x) \geq 0.
$$
This means $\mathbf{M}=\mathbf{A}^T \mathbf{X} \mathbf{A}$ is positive semi-definite.

If we assume that $\mathbf{A}$ has full rank, then $\mathbf{M}$ is positive-definite. Indeed, then  for every non-zero $x\in\mathbb{R}^m$, $\mathbf{A}x$ is also non-zero and thus
$x^T (\mathbf{A}^T \mathbf{X} \mathbf{A})x > 0$.

Comment: I think there is a typo. In the first equation, (Ax)^TX(Ax)^T should be (Ax)^TX(Ax), no? Also, in the last line, shouldn't $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$ be $x \in \mathbb{R}^m$?

Comment: @Ralff Yes, those were definitely typos. I fixed them now. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Nice! That explains why a positive-definite correlation matrix implies a positive-definite covariance matrix. The covariance matrix equals the correlation matrix pre- and post-multiplied by the diagonal matrix of standard deviations.